# WSUS Download from windows update but only approved updates

Tags: group-policy, windows-update

I'm asking to make sure I'm clear on the logic.

Part 1) My goal is to have clients check the WSUS server for approved updates. Then download\install them from windows update.

I believe this can be accomplished by simply selecting do not store update files locally; computers install from Microsoft update - under options on the WSUS server

Then setting the group policy (computer configuration>administrative Template>windows components>windows update>specify internet Microsoft update service location) "Set the alternate download server" set it to blank.

"set the intranet update service for detecting update" would be the WSUS server name

"set the intranet statistics" would be the WSUS server name

Part 2) My goal would be if the client does not have access to the internet pull them from the WSUS server.

what would be the WSUS configuration options, what would be the group policy settings?